# How to compare strings in two files

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have two text files, one file contains entries such as

```
Id         Value
1         apple   
2         orange  
3         mango 
4         banana 
5         strawberry
6         papaya
```

In other file I have entries like

```
Id        Value
6         strawberry 
4         banana
3         orange  
1         mango
2         papaya
5         straw berry
```

I have to match between Ids and the corresponding strings in the value column and find the string correctness. How can this be done?

Comment: Whad do you mean by `string correctness`?

Comment: I think first will be like your test cases and second will be raw data to test..?

Comment: String correctness means that in the above we have 5 strawberry and in second file we have 5 straw berry which is wrong. That is what i meant. It should match with both Id and value here in this case only id 5 matches in both files

Comment: and what if ids don't match (in first file 6 - papaya, in second 6 - strawberry ?

Comment: It should say it as error as false and true if it is same. It should tell as such only one matches and it should return 1 as result

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your desired output. You need to clarify what is "correct" and what is "wrong". It looks like there's only one string that is "correct" in your example (`4  banana`), is that correct?

Comment: yeah 4 banana is also same. sorry i left out that. So 4 banana and 5 strawberry is same. but since strawberry has space in between in file 2, it is wrong in my case. The result should be only 1 that is 4 banana is only matching

Answer (score 3):

If you always have the same number of entries in each files, and if each ID can be join with the same ID in the other file, you could do something like this (this is a proof of concept, you have to improve it):

```
$ join -j1 <(sort -n file1.txt) <(sort -n file2.txt) | 
    awk '{if($2!=$3){k="==> BUG"}else {k=" ==> OK"}print $0,k}'

Id Value Value ==> OK
1 apple  mango ==> BUG
2 orange  papaya ==> BUG
3 mango  orange  ==> BUG
4 banana  banana ==> OK
5 strawberry straw berry ==> BUG
6 papaya strawberry  ==> BUG
```

Note that it won't work 'as-is' if ID #4 is not present in second file for instance.

You should remove headers and keep only `BUG` lines.

```
$ join -j1 <(sort -n file1.txt | tail -n+2) <(sort -n file2.txt | tail -n+2) | 
    awk '($2!=$3){print $0," ==> BUG"}'
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the `tail`; if you simply let `awk` skip the header (`with NR>1`): `join -j1 <(sort -n file1) <(sort -n file2) | awk 'NR>1 && $2!=$3 {print $0," ==> BUG"}'`. - But since the headers are equal anyway you can omit that (`tail` and `NR>1` anyway in your second proposal where only differences are shown)

Answer (score 3):

A straightforward `awk` solution (without pre-sorting or any external tools) could be:

```
awk '
  FNR==1 { next }
  NR==FNR { a[$1] = $2 ; next }
  a[$1] != $2 { print $1, ":", $2, "does not match", a[$1] }
' file1 file2
```

Output for your data:

```
6 : strawberry does not match papaya
3 : orange does not match mango
1 : mango does not match apple
2 : papaya does not match orange
5 : straw does not match strawberry
```

Comment: This approach works even if the number of lines in two files differ.